# How to set the div content dynamically while each load?

Tags: php, jquery, css

Home.html

I have a left menu in which when visitor menu is clicked, it will load visitor.html in the div named 'rightcont'.

```
$(".rightcont").load("visitor.html");
```

Also when the students menu is clicked, it will load students.html on the div rightcont

```
$(".rightcont").load("students.html");
```

But by default i loaded welcome.html in the rightcont when the page is first visited.

My problem is when the user click a link named STUDENTS in some other part of the website, it redirects to home.html in which the 'rightcont' div displays welcome.html. I need rightcont to display students.html.

How to change it dynamically based on the link clicked

Comment: I was about to bust into this question and shout "with jQuery!" but I can see you're already doing that so too-bad-for-me.

Comment: What You mean??? @ Carson Myers

Comment: I suggest you try explaining yourself more clearly and, more importantly, I wouldn't recommend downvoting people who are trying to help you. So good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
return false;
```

to make sure that when clicking the link it doesn't redirect the page.  You can load the div rightcont when the link is clicked.

```
$("#students").click(function() {
    $(".rightcont").load("students.html");
    return false;
});
```

(You need to have id="students" in the anchor tag to make that selector work)

Comment: But the students link and rightcont is in different page, thats the page.........

Comment: You need to pass some variable from the source page, either in a post or injected into the target page.

Answer (score 0):

on the hyperlinks to the student page link to students.php?page=students and add this bit of php to the page

```
if($_get['page'] == "students")
{
?>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(".rightcont").load("students.html"); 
 <script>
 <?
}
else
{
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(".rightcont").load("visitor.html"); 
 <script>
}
```

Comment: This should work, but could be made more robust by making the $_get['page'] a variable, then loading rightcont based on that variable, so it would also work for visitor or any other links.